# Filtering for rows in a Pandas dataframe containing at least one zero

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, range

I am trying to delete all rows in a Pandas data frame that don't have a zero in either of two columns.  My data frame is indexed from 0 to 620.  This is my code:

```
for index in range(0, 621):
    if((zeroes[index,1] != 0) and (zeroes[index,3] != 0)):
        del(zeroes[index,])
```

I keep getting a key error.
KeyError: (0, 1)

My instructor suggested I change the range to test to see if I have bad lines in my data frame.  I did.  I checked the tail of my dataframe and then changed the range to (616, 621).  Then I got the key error: (616, 1).

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code or why I am getting a key error?

This code also produces a key error of (0,1):

```
index = 0
while (index < 621):
    if((zeroes[index,1] != 0) and (zeroes[index,3] != 0)):
        del(zeroes[index,])
index = index + 1
```

Comment: Please always provide a mimimal, complete, verifiable example of your code. The problem is clearly in `zeroes` but we can't help you without knowing what `zeroes` is.

Comment: zeroes is the name of my dataframe.  It contains data on average test scores in Michigan counties.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a manual `for` loop here. Your error probably occurs because `df.__getitem__((x, y))`, which is effectively what `df[x, y]` calls, has no significance.

Instead, use vectorised operations and Boolean indexing. For example, to remove rows where either column 1 or 3 do not equal 0:

```
df = df[df.iloc[:, [1, 3]].eq(0).any(1)]
```

This works because `eq(0)` creates a dataframe of Boolean values indicating equality to zero and `any(1)` filters for rows with any `True` values.

The full form is `df.iloc[:, [1, 3]].eq(0).any(axis=1)`, or `df.iloc[:, [1, 3]].eq(0).any(axis='columns')` for even more clarity. See the docs for [`pd.DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for more details.