# Python3 Pandas Filter by Columns with Unknown Column Names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, filter

Working with a data set comparing rosters with different dates.  It goes through a pivot and we don't know the dates of when the rosters are pulled but the resulting data set is structured like this:

```
colA    ColB    colC    colD    Date:yymmdd    Date:yymmdd    Date:yymmdd
Bob     aa      aa      aa      0              0              1        
Jack    bb      bb      bb      1              1              1        
Steve   cc      cc      cc      0              1              1        
Mary    dd      dd      dd      1              1              1        
Abu     ee      ee      ee      1              1              0
```

I successfully did a fillna for every column after the first 4 columns (they are known).

```
df.iloc[:,4:] = df.iloc[:,4:].fillna(0)  #<-- Fills blanks on every column after column 4.
```

Question:  Now i'm trying to filter the df on the columns that have a zero.  Is there a way to filter by columns after 4?  I tried:

```
df = df[(df.iloc[:,4:] == 0)]   # error
df = df[(df.columns[:,4:] == 0)]   # error
df = df[(df.columns.str.contains(':') == 0)]   # unknown columns do have a ':', but didn't work.
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Looking for a result that only shows the rows with a 0 in any column past #4.

Comment: "Now i'm trying to filter the df on the columns that have a zero." Can you be more precise? What is your desired output?

Comment: Hi jpp, rows to be returned:  Bob, Steve, Abu.  They have a zero after column 4.

Comment: So maybe `df = df[df.iloc[:, 4:].eq(0).any(1)]` ?

Comment: Works!  Can you form that as an answer so I can upvote?  What does ".eq(0).any(1)" mean?

Comment: I'd rather you upvote [this identical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52770645/9209546), and I'll mark this question as a duplicate. The answer works because `eq(0)` creates a dataframe of Boolean values indicating equality to zero and `any(1)` means *any* value is `True` for each row. The full form is `df.iloc[:, 4:].eq(0).any(axis=1)` or `df.iloc[:, 4:].eq(0).any(axis='columns')` for even more clarity.

Comment: Its not an identical question, I did a lot of looking around for this particular filtering use case before asking as a new question.  It is an identical answer to "Why am I getting a Key Error in a for loop range" but that was not close to my question.

Comment: I stopped answering questions several months ago.. feel free to self-answer with information in my last comment to help others :)

Answer (score 2):

Below snippet will give you one Dataframe containing True and False as cell values of df.

```
df.iloc[:, 4:].eq(x)
```

If you want to have only those rows where x is there, then you can `any()` clause.
like the way @jpp has shown in his answer.

In your case, it will be `df[df.iloc[:, 4:].eq(0).any(1)]`

This will give you all the rows of Dataframe, where rows have atleast one '0' as data value

Answer (score -1):

If all values are 0 or bigger, use min :

```
df[df.columns[:,4:].min(axis = 1) == 0]
```